# R data.table get maximum value per row for multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

I've got a data.table in R which looks like that one:

```
dat <- structure(list(de = c(1470L, 8511L, 3527L, 2846L, 2652L, 831L
), fr = c(14L, 81L, 36L, 16L, 30L, 6L), it = c(9L, 514L, 73L, 
37L, 91L, 2L), ro = c(1L, 14L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 0L)), .Names = c("de", 
"fr", "it", "ro"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I now wanna create a new data.table (having exactly the same columns) but holding only the maximum value per row. The values in the other columns should simply be NA.

The data.table could have any number of columns (the data.table above is just an example).

The desired output table would look like this:

```
     de fr it ro
1: 1470 NA NA NA
2: 8511 NA NA NA
3: 3527 NA NA NA
4: 2846 NA NA NA
5: 2652 NA NA NA
6:  831 NA NA NA
```

Comment: why is this a `data.table` instead of a matrix?

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with what the OP is attempting here: (1) this really looks like a case where data should be kept in a matrix rather than a data.frame or data.table; (2) there's no reason to want this sort of output that I can think of; and (3) doing any standard operations with the output will be a hassle.

With that said...

```
dat2 = dat
is.na(dat2)[-( 1:nrow(dat) + (max.col(dat)-1)*nrow(dat) )] <- TRUE
# or, as @PierreLafortune suggested
is.na(dat2)[col(dat) != max.col(dat)] <- TRUE

# or using the data.table package
dat2 = dat[rep(NA_integer_, nrow(dat)), ]
mc   = max.col(dat)
for (i in seq_along(mc)) set(dat2, i = i, j = mc[i], v = dat[i, mc[i]])
```

Comment: I'm not sure the algebra is right, but the OP's example is not general enough for testing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me whether you mean that you want to use the data.table package, or if you are satisfied with making a data.frame using only base functions. It is certainly possible to do the latter.

Here is one solution, which uses only max() and which.max() and relies on the fact that an empty data.frame will fill in all of the remaining cells with NA to achieve a rectangular structure.

```
maxdat <- data.frame()
  for (col in names(dat)) {
  maxdat[which.max(dat[,col]), col] <- max(dat[,col])
}
```

Comment: Now that the OP has updated the desired output, this solution indeed no longer makes sense. But I can't understand why the desired output makes sense either. The original column names appeared to correspond to country codes in Europe. Now that information is lost.